# What is the scope of a unique_ptr returned from a function?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Would this work properly? (see example)

```
unique_ptr<A> source()
{
    return unique_ptr<A>(new A);
}


void doSomething(A &a)  
{  
    // ...
}  

void test()  
{  
    doSomething(*source().get());   // unsafe?
    // When does the returned unique_ptr go out of scope?
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A `unique_ptr` returned from a function does not have scope, because scope only applies to names.

In your example, the lifetime of the temporary `unique_ptr` ends at the semicolon. (So yes, it would work properly.) In general, a temporary object is destroyed when the full-expression that lexically contains the rvalue whose evaluation created that temporary object is completely evaluated.

Comment: So the function doSomething is executed before the unique_ptr is destroyed?

Comment: @tache: yes. That's true for any return value. If it went out of scope immediately, returning *anything* from a function would be rather useless. :)

Comment: @tache: Yes. The order is 1. call `source` 2. call `get` 3. dereference 4. call `doSomething` 5. destroy temporary `unique_ptr`

Comment: @jalf: But please note that unique_ptr itself is not used in the call to the function doSomething.. only the raw pointer that is contained within unique_ptr is used.

Comment: The same logic still applies. The temporary holding the return value *has* to stay in scope long enough to be used, or it'd be worthless. As the other commenters have said, your code is perfectly safe

Answer (score 5):

Temporary values get destroyed after evaluating the "full expression", which is (roughly) the largest enclosing expression - or in this case the whole statement. So it's safe; the unique_ptr is destroyed after doSomething returns.

Comment: Microsoft: "All temporaries created as a result of expression evaluation are destroyed at the end of the expression statement (that is, at the semicolon), or at the end of the controlling expressions for for, if, while, do, and switch statements." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8kfxa78(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @tache See 1.9/12 and 12.2/3 in the C++03 standard for the definitive answer.

Comment: @tache: Not free (but a good investment, imho). A bit of googling will find you some committee drafts that are very close to the official version.

Comment: After a long search I found this: "Final Committee Draft (FCD) of the C++0x standard" http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf

Comment: Without good examples though it's hard to know what they mean exactly. So I think this document is only for C++ guru's.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine.  Consider

```
int Func()
{
  int ret = 5;

  return ret;
}

void doSomething(int a) { ... }


doSomething(Func());
```

Even though you're returning ret on the stack it is okay because it's within the calling scope.

Comment: But Func() returns a copy of ret anyway. So this example is not really relevant i think.